# How to add "required" attribute to selected option in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of options and upon selection of option the input fieldsset drops down to enter values, for Box it`s dimensions and so on. All fields from fieldset needs to be marked with required attribute

```
<select id="product" class="product" name="product">
    <option value="none" default>----- Select product from list below -----</option>
    <option value="dvd">DVD disc</option>
    <option value="furniture">Furniture</option>
</select>
```

for DVD

```
<fieldset class="show-form dvd">
   <legend>DVD size: </legend>
   <div>
     <label for="dvd">Size: </label>
     <input class="dvd" id="dvd" type="number" step="0.001" min="0" placeholder="Enter DVD size"/>
     <p>Please provide DVD disc size in MB</p>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

and for Furniture

```
<fieldset class="show-form furniture">
  <legend>Furniture dimensions: </legend>
  <table>
     <tr>
       <td>
          <label for="height">Height: </label>
       </td>
       <td>
          <input class="furniture" id="height" type="number"
              />
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
          <label for="width">Width: </label>
       </td>
       <td>
          <input class="furniture" id="width" type="number"/>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>
          <label for="length">Length: </label>
       </td>
       <td>
          <input class="furniture" id="length" type="number"/>
       </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
<p>Please provide dimensions for furniture in HxWxL format</p>
</fieldset>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('.product').change(function () {
        var option = $(this).find('option:selected');
        var value = option.val();
        $('.show-form').hide();
        $('.' + value).show(300).attr('required', true)
    });
});
```

But running jQuery it adds fields even to hidden fieldset. How to make it work that it adds required attribute only to the fields of selected option(visible)?
Any help appreciated.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.product').change(function () {
        var option = $(this).find('option:selected');
        var value = option.val();
        $('.show-form').hide();
        $('.' + value).show(300).attr('required', true)
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Product Add</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="form" action="index2.php" method="post">
          <td>
            <label for="product">Select type of product: </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="product" class="product" name="product">
              <option value="none" default>----- Select product from list below -----</option>
              <option value="dvd">DVD disc</option>
              <option value="box">Box</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <fieldset class="show-form dvd">
        <legend>DVD size: </legend>
        <div>
        <label for="dvd">Size: </label>
        <input class="dvd" id="dvd" type="number" step="0.001" min="0" placeholder="Enter DVD size"/>
        <p>Please provide DVD disc size in MB</p>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      
      <fieldset class="show-form box">
        <legend>Box dimensions: </legend>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="height">Height: </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input class="box" id="height" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Height of Box"
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="width">Width: </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input class="box" id="width" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Width of Box"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="length">Length: </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input class="box" id="length" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Length of Box"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
          <p>Please provide dimensions for Box in HxWxL format</p>
      </fieldset>

<input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
    <script src="js/hideForm.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to use `callback` for this. `replace $('.' + value).show(300).attr('required', true) with $('.' + value).show(300,function(){ $('.' + value).attr('required', true)})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to target the `input`s and `select`s to set required, not the table itself. There was also a misplaced `</tr></table>` which I removed. Lastly, if you call `.change()` on page load, then it will hide your tables right away and mark all `input`/`select`s as optional until a product is selected.

Note: you'll need to add back in `action="index2.php"` - the form isn't submitting on SO when this value is set.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.product').change(function() {
    var option = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var value = '.' + option.val();
    
    // hide all tables, set all fields to optional
    $('.show-form').hide();
    $('.show-form input, .show-form select').removeAttr('required');
    
    // show selected table, set selected input/selects as required
    $(value).show(300);
    $(value + ' input, ' + value + ' select').attr('required', true);
  });
  $('.product').change(); // hide tables and set fields to optional on load
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Product Add</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="form">
    <td>
      <label for="product">Select type of product: </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="product" class="product" name="product">
        <option value="none" default>----- Select product from list below -----</option>
        <option value="dvd">DVD disc</option>
        <option value="box">Box</option>
      </select>
    </td>

    <fieldset class="show-form dvd">
      <legend>DVD size: </legend>
      <div>
        <label for="dvd">Size: </label>
        <input class="dvd" id="dvd" type="number" step="0.001" min="0" placeholder="Enter DVD size" />
        <p>Please provide DVD disc size in MB</p>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="show-form box">
      <legend>Box dimensions: </legend>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="height">Height: </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="box" id="height" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Height of Box" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="width">Width: </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="box" id="width" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Width of Box" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="length">Length: </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="box" id="length" type="number" min="0" placeholder="Length of Box" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>Please provide dimensions for Box in HxWxL format</p>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery.validate.js

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js
```

The Sample link below

```
https://codepen.io/prasanthmj/pen/pAzaf
```

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers. At least move the code from your codepen link to this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer